# I want to update a checkbox which checkbox selected in parent account so please any one give ma idea how to write a trigger ?:

Tags: trigger

I have three child record and one parent and i have one custom field profile which datatype is check box i want to update my child account's check box depends on parent account.

Comment: Akash, you don't need to create a trigger or update the child field everytime, because formula fields will help you to get the updated value always without any trigger or update. Please explain in detail the object and field names and data type on both the Parent and Child object, we can help you with formula field.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly area of task.

You don't need to write trigger. Just use formula field on child object, that copies value from parent object.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_cross_object.htm&type=0

Answer (score 0):

trigger UpdateChildRecord on Account ( after update ,after insert ){
    LIST ac = new LIST();
    Set accountIds = new Set();
    LIST newRecord = new LIST();

```
//ac = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE ParentId = '0016F000021dTc3'];
Account ac_new = trigger.new[0];
Account ac1_old = trigger.old[0];

System.debug('New Value'+ac_new.Special__c);
System.debug('Old Value'+ac1_old.Special__c);
LIST<Account> childAccounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE ParentId = :ac_new.Id];
if(ac_new.Special__c != ac1_old.Special__c){
  // Get all related child record by ParentID to set Special
    for (Account childAccount : childAccounts){
        childAccount.Special__c = ac_new.Special__c;
    }    
}
if(ac_new.Local__c != ac1_old.Local__c){
  // Get all related child record by ParentID to set Local
    for (Account childAccount : childAccounts){
        childAccount.Local__c = ac_new.Local__c;
    }    
}
update childAccounts;
```

}